# Mouse scroll is not working in IE browser in Kendo Grid with virtualization.

Tags: jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I have a common control for grid and scroll is working fine in all browser but Scroll in not working on IE 10/11 (using mouse wheel scroll) with the visualization in Kendo UI grid.

Code snippet is as :--

dataList.kendoGrid({
                name: "BaseGrid",
                dataBound: self.handleDataBoundEventHandler,
                dataBinding: self.options.dataBindingEventHandler,
                editable: self.options.editable,
                beforeEdit: self.options.beforeEdit,
                edit: self.options.edit,
                editCell: self.options.editCell,
                batch: this.batch,
                navigatable: self.options.navigatable || true,
                init: self.options.initialize,
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    group: self.options.group,
                    transport: transportOptions,
                    serverPaging: serverPaging,
                    serverSorting: serverSorting,
                    serverFiltering: serverFiltering,
                    pageSize: self.pageSize,
                    schema: {
                        model: self.options.model,
                        data: function (response) {
                            if (self.options.jsonData) {
                                response.dataList = self.options.jsonData;
                            }
                            response = self.handleOnSuccess(response);

```
                        self.NoRecordOnsuccess(response);

                        if (self.options.isDynamicColumnsAvailable) {
                            self.trigger("configureColumnDataFetched", response.dataList);
                        }
                        if (self.options.collection) {
                            self.options.collection.set(response.dataList);
                        }
                        return response.dataList;
                    },
                    total: function (response) {
                        return response.totalRecords;
                    }
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    // Changing sort icon on sort change
                    self.changeSortIcon(this);
                    self.modifySenderData(e.sender);
                    if (self.options.changeEventHandler) {
                        self.options.changeEventHandler(e);
                    }
                },
                requestStart: function (e) {
                    if (self.options.requestStart) {
                        self.options.requestStart(e);
                    }
                },
                sort: self.options.userPreferenceSort || self.options.defaultSort
            },
            sortable: self.options.sortable,
            selectable: self.options.selectable,
            filterable: self.options.filterable,
            scrollable: {
                virtual: _.isUndefined(self.options.virtualScrollable) ? true : self.options.virtualScrollable
            },
            reorderable: self.options.reorderable,
            resizable: self.options.resizable,
            columnReorder: function (e) {
                // Update the User preference model with new sequence no
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self.updateColumnSequenceNumber(self.getDataList().columns);
                }, 5);
            },
            columnResize: function (e) {
                // Update the User preference model with new width of column
                self.updateUserPreference(e.column.preferenceColumnName, "resize", e.newWidth);
            },
            enableSwipe: true,
            columns: this.getGridColumns()
        });
    },
```

If any one have any solution  please let me know.

Comment: did you find any solution?